# Show logged in user data on another activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After logging in with PHP and MySQL in my `mainactivity`, if the username and password is correct the user will be sent to the `welcomeactivity`. Here I have a `TextView`. In this `TextView` I want to show the username and password of the logged in user.

Comment: How do you check if user is authenticated? The user enter his name in a text view or in a webview?

Comment: Please rethink showing the user's password in plaintext on your application: this is insecure and unnecessary.

Comment: it was an example, In a EditText ( in the login screen the user enters his username ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the user is successfully logged in, at that time you have the user name and password .
 Now you have to start `WelcomeActivity` with the user name and password values so that it can be accessed in `WelcomeActivity`
You write -

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
in.putExtra("user_name", <your user name >);
in.putExtra("password", <your password>);
startActivity(in);
```

Now in your `WelcomeActivity` onCreate() method you fetch these values like -

```
String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name");
String pwd = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");
```

Now that you have username and password in your `WelcomeActivity`, you can who them anyway you want.

Comment: Thanks this worked, but does this work when it auto-logins the user aswell?

Comment: This should wherever  you want to start WelcomeActivity and you have the user name and password values.

Comment: Lets say I want the email from the database of the logged in user to, how to get that data? Becouse that cannot be send within the intent...?

Comment: That's a different question. Please raise another question for that.